# Using YouTube Data API V3 in Android application?

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to use YouTube Data API V3 in my application to do the following:

1. Retrieve the playlists in my YouTube channel.
2. Retrieve a the list of videos in each playlist.

Now I'm confused, which SDK shall I use the [Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/youtube/v3) (works on Android)

or shall I use the [Android Player APIs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications), but it seems that it does not provide retrieving the playlists info, it just plays videos within the app.

or can I use the REST APIs and parse the responses manually ?

would you please recommend a method ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the YouTube Data API v3. This will work on Android. The Player API is for playing YouTube videos in your views. If you want to fetch playlist information and play videos, you would use both in your application.